# gmake error when using Gnu multi precision library C++

Tags: c++, precision

I write this simple program in Netbeans.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    mpf_t a,b,c;
    mpf_init(a);

    return 0;
}
```

The error that I get is:

```
gmake[2]: Entering directory `/mnt/home/arigi/test/xx'
mkdir -p dist/Release/GNU-Linux-x86
g++     -o dist/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/xx build/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o -L../../lib -Wl,-rpath,../../lib
build/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `__gmpf_init'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [dist/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/xx] Error 1
gmake[2]: Leaving directory `/mnt/home/arigi/test/xx'
gmake[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/home/arigi/test/xx'
gmake: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 253ms)
```

I tried mpfr and I'm getting the same error. When I delete the

```
mpf_init(a);
```

The compilation is successful. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link against `gmp` library, see [GMP Headers and Libraries](https://gmplib.org/manual/Headers-and-Libraries.html#Headers-and-Libraries) for full details.